# Cant Post To Server Well

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsmutableurlrequest

i am trying to post to a server in the following code.
i cant receive the response that i need to get.
think i am making something wrong, need some help

```
    NSString *uuid = @"acdede9b-6fa6-44d0-8837-cd11771139be";
NSString *rec = @"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";
NSString *ServerContent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"registerRecipt.aspx?udid=%@&receipt=%@",uuid,rec];
NSData *requestdata = [ServerContent dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"myserverurl"]];
request.timeoutInterval = 20;
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:requestdata];
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

error

> The page cannot be displayed
>
> - Open **IIS Help**, which is accessible in IIS Manager (inetmgr),

Comment: Your question is quite confusing.  What kind of error or bogus response are you getting?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>The page cannot be displayed</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=Windows-1252">
<STYLE type="text/css">
  BODY { font: 8pt/12pt verdana }
<ul>
<li>Open <b>IIS Help</b>, which is accessible in IIS Manager (inetmgr),
</ul>

</TD></TR></TABLE></BODY></HTML>

Comment: i cant post all of the response

Comment: Edit your original question to include this response and try to clarify what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the `Content-Length` header:

```
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] 
forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
```